# translate.py doesnt use embedding?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to get my head around the lstm-with-attention script in tensorflow:
https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate

This does not use embeddings, even though it calls embedding_rnn_seq2seq, but fed into this call are only the scalar word-IDs, not any kind of embedding vectors.

At least I cannot find the embedding parameters, nor the matrix, nor a possibility to feed pretrained embeddings. Any idea? Thx a bunch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in [`translate.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d9c173fc7adf9443d58310dd08a84b9eb89d4c8f/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.py) *does* use an embedding, but its creation is buried deep in the implementation. The model uses the (undocumented) [`tf.nn.seq2seq.embedding_attention_seq2seq()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4172ca2cd7ac34be67bda2600944d284e8907b95/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L754) function, which [creates](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4172ca2cd7ac34be67bda2600944d284e8907b95/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L814) a [`tf.nn.rnn_cell.EmbeddingWrapper`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/rnn_cell.html#EmbeddingWrapper) that internally creates the embedding matrix.