# TensorFlow -- Understanding Embeddings in translate.py

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

My understanding was that translate.py implements an encoder-decoder model, one step of which is translating sentences from the input language to fixed-length vetors.  From the post at [translate.py doesnt use embedding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508356/translate-py-doesnt-use-embedding) and my own investigation of the code, I thought the sentence embeddings would be stored in embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/EmbeddingWrapper/embedding:0.  But this is a variable of a shape corresponding to my input vocabulary size X rnn layer size.  I don't understand how I can conceptually interpret it as encodings of sentences.  Where's the error in my understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the embedding layer's named **seq2seq/embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/EmbeddingWrapper/embedding:0**

you can show all variables with :

```
for var in tf.trainable_variables():
  print var.name
```

in the **embedding_attention_seq2seq**() function definition

Comment: How do you interpret the value stored in that variable?  The question was not about how to get the value of that variable but what the value means.

Comment: The embedding variable contains a matrix of size : vocab_size x embedding_size representing each word in the vocabulary as a vector of size embedding_size. If you save the matrix in a tsv format you could visualize it in http://projector.tensorflow.org/. The values represent how words are related to each other. Hope I clarifyed things.